# Как создать расширение, которое отображало бы актуальный z-index у конкретного объекта?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, z-index

Есть сайт: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/z-index
И там есть "интерактивный пример", где нажимаются кнопки и z-index у объектов меняется в коде:
`<div id="example-element" style="z-index: 5;">Change my z-index</div>==$0`, там на 3,4,5...
Мне необходимо создать расширение, которое отображало бы актуальный z-index у конкретного объекта, т.е. мне нужно задать в переменную значение z-index объекта и вывести эту цифру в расширение.
В popup.js добавил следующие строчки `const ser = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('[data-id="example-element"]'),null).getPropertyValue("z-index"); document.write(ser);`
но не работает, помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему, желательно на чистом JS

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Какую проблему? Вы же нам рабочий пример вроде бы показываете...

Comment: DevTools это умеет

Comment: Что в вашем понимании должен возвращать ваш код? Что по вашему есть `z-index`? Большая часть элементов на сайте стоит с использованием дефолтного значения `z-index` = `auto`.

Comment: @ΝNL993 в расширении ничего не показывается, пустой квадратик, в панели разработчика выдается ошибка и первая строчка с получением переменной выделена желтым.

Comment: @De.Minov ну как, там на сайте не дефолтное значение и оно меняется

Comment: @Олег так потому что popup.js используется для самого попапа, а вам нужен background.js (В манифесте допишите `background: { scripts: 'background.js' }`), т.к. у popup.js по идее доступ должен быть только к попапу, а у background.js к самой странице.